# How to Make Content Inside showModalBottomSheet Scrollable when it consists webview inside?

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I am working on a Flutter application where I'm using a **`showModalBottomSheet`** to display some content, including a **`WebViewWidget`**. The issue I'm facing is that the content inside the **`showModalBottomSheet`** is not scrollable when it exceeds the available height. I would like to make the content scrollable so that users can navigate through the entire content of the **`WebViewWidget`** when it doesn't fit within the given height. webview will of infinity height.

I've tried wrapping the **`WebViewWidget`** with a **`SingleChildScrollView`**, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. The content inside the **`showModalBottomSheet`** remains non-scrollable.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      elevation: 10,
      enableDrag: true,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
      builder: (BuildContext sheetContext) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
            return SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Center(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 2.0,
                        width: 20.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 5.0,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: goBack,
                          icon: const Icon(
                            CupertinoIcons.arrow_left,
                            size: 30,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                            copiedText,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            maxLines: 1,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
                        // IconButton(
                        //     icon: const Icon(
                        //       Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                        //       size: 30,
                        //       color: Colors.black,
                        //     ),
                        //     onPressed: widget.fn),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: WebViewWidget(
                        controller: controller,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    )
```

Could you please help me understand what I might be missing or suggest an alternative approach to making the content inside the **`showModalBottomSheet`** scrollable? I want to achieve a similar behavior to how Google Chrome shows a bottom search bar when selecting text.

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your ModalBottomSheet is draggable that's why it blocks the scroll control on the webview.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    elevation: 10,
    enableDrag: false,    // disable it
    ...
    ...
);
```